# select child table that contains only specific status

Tags: sql, oracle

Master table:

```
orderno    status
======     ======
123        ACTIVE
456        INACTIVE
```

Child table example, I want to select new and close status:

```
orderno     status
=======     ======
123         NEW
123         CLOSE
123         PENDING
123         PENDING
```

result: no row selected

Child table example, I want to select new and close status:

```
orderno     status
=======     ======
456         NEW
456         NEW
456         CLOSE
456         CLOSE
```

result2: successful select orderno 456 out.

Comment: Uhm... am I missing something, or are those two examples exactly the same, except for the result? Why are the order numbers all `123`?

Comment: Yeah I think your examples aren't quite right...

Comment: is a child table that tie with master table that have orderno 123,

one to many relationship, maybe i add in master table to have bigger picture

Comment: exactly what is the query condition? select status (new,close) and order no ? what is the condition?

Comment: i only want to select set of result that child table contains status new and close,

if child table contains status new , close and pending, the result wont be display

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT orderno,sum(decode(status,'NEW',0,'CLOSE',0,1))
FROM test1 group by orderno 
having sum(decode(status,'NEW',0,'CLOSE',0,1))=0;
```

Here is the table data(Test1) and o/p

```
123 NEW
123 CLOSE
123 PENDING
456 NEW
456 CLOSE

456 0
```